# Mac OS X Core Graphics: sending produced image to stdout instead of saving to file

Tags: macos, core-graphics, stdout

I'm generating an image and I can successfully save it to file.

```
urlRef = (CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath: filePath];

imgDestRef = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(urlRef,
                                             kUTTypeJPEG, 
                                             1, 
                                             NULL);

/* ... */

CGImageDestinationFinalize(imgDestRef);
```

Now I need to send the generated image to **stdout** instead of writing it to a file.

I've tried to set **filePath** to **/dev/stdout** but CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL fails.

-

Other option is writing to memory and then reading the data and writing to stdout, this way:

```
jpgDataRef = CFDataCreateMutable(NULL, 0);

imgDestinationRef = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(jpgDataRef,
                                                     kUTTypeJPEG, 
                                                     1, 
                                                     NULL);

/* ... */

CGImageDestinationFinalize(imgDestRef); /* STEP 1 */ 

NSFileHandle *stdoutFH = [NSFileHandle fileHandleWithStandardOutput]; /* STEP 2 */
[stdoutFH writeData:(NSData *)jpgDataRef];
```

But I'd prefer a one-step approach, with **CGImageDestinationFinalize** to write directly to **stdout** (*assuming going this way would be faster or less memory-consuming*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a [custom CGDataConsumer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGDataConsumer/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGDataConsumerCreate) whose [put bytes callback](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGDataConsumer/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CGDataConsumerPutBytesCallback) writes the bytes using `write` or NSFileHandle, then [create an image destination with that data consumer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageDestination/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageDestinationCreateWithDataConsumer).

You could probably wrap this in an object that takes an NSFileHandle, creates a data consumer around it, and exposes a method or two for adding images.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
 CGImageDestinationCreateWithData
```

to write to an NSMutableData object.

Get the bytes with the `NSMutableData:bytes` method and output with printf or putc or whatever you like?

Comment: Alternatively, make a custom CGDataConsumer that writes the bytes to stdout, and [create your image destination with that consumer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageDestination/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageDestinationCreateWithDataConsumer).

Comment: (By the way, neither `printf` nor `putc` is a good way to write bytes from an NSData object. Consider using `write` or NSFileHandle instead.)

Comment: @PeterHosey: It seem to me that CGDataConsumer is the way to go to achieve the result is a single step (without writing to memory with CGImageDestinationCreateWithData and then reading the data and sending to stdout). If you could post that approach as an answer with little more details I'd really appreciate (and mark it as correct answer).